# Align views by center line in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

I have root `RelativeLayout` and child views.

After some view V1 I want to place 3 views: `TextView` TV1, `TextView` TV2 and `ProgressBar` Progress. Ofcouse, Progress have height larger than textviews. After this 3 views placed other views.

How I can place TV1, TV2, Progress with 'center' line? Without using any additional container, for example: `LinearLayout`.

[image]

Comment: You can give your Views an `android:centerVertical="true"` attribute

Comment: why you don't want a container? I think that nesting layouts are always a good approach

Comment: @Carlos Robless, I think: less containers, less wasteful on render.

Comment: anyways that's is the best that you can do. 
If you still don't want, you can calculate the height of the 3 elements in runtime, and add the proper margin programatically

Comment: Did you try something like: android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/progress", or reverse?

Answer (score 1):

Pick a reference view (let's say progressBar in your case) and align the other views relative to both its top **AND** bottom. This way they will become centered relative to its horizontal axis.

```
android:layout_alignTop ="@+id/reference_progressbar_id"
android:layout_alignBottom ="@id/reference_progressbar_id"
```

Answer (score 0):

Step-1
Create a `LinearLayout` which contains these three view and set `android:gravity="center"` to the linearlayoutlike following

```
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/action_header_RL"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:gravity="center"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="123"/>

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="456"/>

     <ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: already, thanks, I know about this  implementation. But I want use only root RelativeLayout.

Comment: @YShinkarev Use RelativeLayout as root but inside that you can use LinearLayout containing these three views.

Answer (score -1):

Add `android:centerVertical="true"` to the views you want to be centered, but this has no guarantee that they will not overlap any other views you add to the layout.

Answer (score -1):

keep this property with tv1 tv2 and progress

<
android:layout_centerVertical="true">

and keep tv1    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

and tv2 to_Rightof  tv1
and progress keep to_RightOf tv2

Comment: @Mahmoud Elmorabea, @Frank N. Stein don't work `android:centerVertical` because I use `layout_below` (below V1).

Answer (score -1):

```
    Try This Below Code:

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ANDROID"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/TextViewValue" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Layout" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/TextViewValue" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: problem of your code, that you don't use views above/below TV/Progress.